# Adjective for "relating to a whole"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

I am trying to find an adjective or word that describes something that is relative/responsive to a larger whole. The context I am interested is in music, e.g. a musical part  in a song that is is particularly responsive to the other parts in the song. To give a better idea, I have a good example word for the opposite idea. An *idiosyncratic* guitar part in song, would be a part that sounds fairly disjunct with other parts, not naturally relating with them and starkly stands out as it's "own thing". But what is an antonym for "idiosyncratic" in this context?

The word I'm looking for is one which explains said musical part as in it's nature as an entity rather than an aesthetic, for instance "conjunctive" springs to mind, yet this would fall to much in the latter category

Comment: How about [holistic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/holistic)?

Comment: "integrated"? As opposed to standing out as separate.

Answer (score 1):

> The context I am interested is in music, e.g. a musical part in a song that is is particularly responsive to the other parts in the song. . . But what is an antonym for "idiosyncratic" in this context?

Try [**harmonious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harmonious):

> **1** : having agreement among musical components : musically concordant • *harmonious* voices
>   **2** : having the parts agreeably related : CONGRUOUS • blended into a *harmonious* whole • *harmonious* medley of small vaulted chambers —Norman Douglas
>   **3** : marked by accord in sentiment or action
>   • *harmonious* relationship between church and state —H. D. Hazeltine

Comment: Dadgummit, I hate you.  (in a good way.  8^)  I should have come up with that.  +1 for the best answer.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Sometimes I have a good day. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a few options for you.  *(All definitions from the Oxford Dictionaries)*

***Concord*** is a noun that means to be in agreement or in harmony.

> ***[concord](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concord)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> 1. *formal* Agreement or harmony between people or groups.
>
>    *‘a pact of peace and concord’*
>
>    1.1 *[count noun]* A treaty.
>
>    *‘a concord was to be drawn up’*
> 2. *Grammar* Agreement between words in gender, number, case, person, or any other grammatical category which affects the forms of the words.
> 3. *Music*
>      *[count noun]* A chord that is pleasing or satisfactory in itself.

There is an adjective form, ***concordant***:

> ***[concordant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/concordant)***
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> 1. In agreement; consistent.
>
>    *‘the answers were roughly concordant’*
>
>    1.1 Music In harmony.

Related is ***consonance***:

> ***[consonance](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consonance)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> 1. Agreement or compatibility between opinions or actions.
>
>    *‘consonance between conservation measures and existing agricultural practice’*
>      *‘a constitution in consonance with the people's customs’*
>
>    1.1 The recurrence of similar-sounding consonants in close proximity, especially in prosody.
>
>    *‘the abrupt quality of the sound is echoed in the final ‘t’ consonance of ‘discreet’ and ‘shut’’*
>
>    1.2 *[Music]* A combination of notes which are in harmony with each other due to the relationship between their frequencies.
>
>    *‘all music creates tension and release, dissonance and consonance’*
>      *[count noun]*  *‘the tendency to place strong consonances in lower parts’*

The adjective form of *consonance* is ***consonant***, but you have to be careful that folks don't think you're talking about the letters that aren't vowels.

> ***[consonant](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/consonant)***
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> 1. attributive Denoting or relating to a consonant.
>
>    *‘a consonant phoneme’*
> 2. *[consonant with]* In agreement or harmony with.
>
>    *‘the findings are consonant with other research’*
>
>    2.1 Music Making a harmonious interval or chord.
>
>    *‘the bass is consonant with all the upper notes’*

Lastly, there is ***unison*** which can apparently be used as an adjective (though I've never seen it used that way):

> ***[unison](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unison)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> 1. Simultaneous performance or utterance of action or speech.
>
>    *‘‘Yes, sir,’ said the girls in unison’*
> 2. *[Music ]*
>      Coincidence in pitch of sounds or notes.
>
>    *‘the flutes play in unison with the violas’*
>
>    2.1 *[count noun]* A combination of notes, voices, or instruments at the same pitch or (especially when singing) in octaves.
>
>    *‘good unisons are formed by flutes, oboes, and clarinets’*
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> Performed in unison.
>
> *‘unison congregational singing’*

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, hmm. Hollistic and concordant are fairly close. Consonant is a problem just because the context is music, and in music if all the other parts in a song are playing dissonant intervals/notes it is more (insert hard to find word here) to play a disssonant melodic part.

Comment: @JemGrant -- Did you see the other answer, _Harmonious_?  To be honest, I think that's the best answer (and I'm kicking myself for not coming up with it!)

Comment: Harmonius has the same issue as consonant, being that it is has a very specific meaning in the context of music. For instance a percussive part, that is devoid of musical harmony, could be playin a part that is very (adjective). Congrous, which is mentioned in the same answer is better, but there is still yet to be a good answer that explains the idea specifically as an entity rather than aesthetic quality, the way the antonymn "idiosyncratic" does. Hollistic is the closest to